# How to delete a Kubeflow cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubeflow

I tried to install KubeFlow but use the wrong region, how to delete it?
I tried to do it from Kubernetes clsuter but keep getting the same error when I try to create a new one:

```
Error 409: 'projects/dpe-cloud-mle/global/deployments/kubeflow' already exists and cannot be created., duplicate
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a feature of Deployment Manager, which is used to create the cluster.
If you create any resource using DM, but edit or delete it manually (=elsewhere in the console), the record of it remains unchanged in the DM.

To fix your issue, navigate to [Deployment Manager in your GCP Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/dm/deployments) and delete the relevant deployment. Then you will be able to re-install KubeFlow without this error.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can also remove the deployment via the command line as mentioned on the [GKE set-up instructions](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/started/getting-started-gke/)

```
${KUBEFLOW_SRC}/scripts/kfctl.sh delete all
```

Answer (score 0):

run the following set of commands to delete all resources associated with the kubeflow deployment:

//Delete the deployment via deployment manager

gcloud deployment-manager --project=${PROJECT} deployments delete 
${DEPLOYMENT_NAME}

//Delete your Cloud Storage bucket when you’ve finished with it:
    gsutil rm -r gs://${BUCKET_NAME}

Delete the container images uploaded to Container Registry:
// Find the digest id for each container image:

gcloud container images list-tags gcr.io/${PROJECT}/${DEPLOYMENT_NAME}-train
gcloud container images list-tags gcr.io/${PROJECT}/${DEPLOYMENT_NAME}-web-ui

// Delete each image:

gcloud container images delete gcr.io/$PROJECT/${DEPLOYMENT_NAME}- 
train:$DIGEST_ID
gcloud container images delete gcr.io/$PROJECT/${DEPLOYMENT_NAME}-web- 
ui:$DIGEST_ID